# Help understanding the grammar of this sentence

Tags: grammar

> 「―――八人目は良かった。帰ったらもう一度やってみよう」
>   **黄理は今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人、三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた手段を思い返す。**
>   そこには楽しみも苦しみもない。 
>   七夜黄理には、そういった感情が欠落している。
>   故に彼は七夜の当主に相応しい。
>   殺人を愉しむのでもなく恐れるのでもなく。ただ行為として没頭できる事が、殺人鬼としての天性なのだ。
>
> [The eighth one went down pretty good. When we get home I'll try again]
>   **Kiri Nanaya...**
>   In that there is no enjoyment nor regret.
>   Nanaya Shiki Lacks those emotions.
>   That is why is well fit for the position of family head.
>   Without enjoying killing nor fearing it. Simply as an act in which he can immerse himself is because of his natural predisposition of a killer.

殺めて回った=Is 回る　an auxiliary verb here? What does this compound mean?
うちの一人=One person out of a group
三十余人の中で=amongst 30 people of the other group
最も迅速に=Fastest
仕留められた=To dispose of/ To kill (potential)
手段=Concrete way to reach a goal.
思い返す=Think back.

I tried to analyze how all of this ties together grammaticaly but I am no sure.

> 黄理は今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人、三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた手段を思い返す。
>   Kiri, tonight one out of the people he killed, amongst those 30 of the other group he thinks back about the fastest way he was able to kill.

So rephrasing that

> Tonight amongst the 30 members of the other group he thinks back about the one of those who he killed with the fastest method.

Could It be parsed like this?

今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人 and 三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた手段 are coordinates and both of them together are the Direct object of 思い返す.

I do not understand why after
黄理は今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人
there is no conjunction to
三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた手段.
I would think there would be some conjunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

回る: *around* (as in *go around*, *shop around*)

> 15 動詞の連用形に付いて、**そのあたりを…する**、**あちこち…する**意を表す。「のたうち―・る」「走り―・る」「逃げ―・る」

殺して回る = go around and kill

余: *a little over ～*, *a bit more than ～*

> ４ 数を表す語に付いて、**その数より少し多い**意を表す。おおよその数を示してその端数を漠然という場合に用いる。…あまり。「二十―年の労苦」

三十余人 = thirty-some people, (a little) over 30 people

---

As for the basic structure of the sentence, 黄理 is the subject, 思い返す is the verb, and the remainder is the long object of 思い返す.

> 黄理は[今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人、三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた手段]を思い返す。

- 今夜殺めて回ったうちの一人: one of those whom he went around and killed tonight
- (三十余人の中で最も迅速に仕留められた→)手段: the method by which he could kill the quickest among over 30 people

The comma after 一人 indicates the author is rephrasing the part before it. Honestly, I feel this part is a bit awkward, because the author is rephrasing 一人 to 手段 . But we can get the meaning, anyway.